# Function properly allocates memory the first time it is called, but the second time it doesn't

Tags: c

I have to read a "database" from console. The input is structured as follows:

```C
[nr of food types]
food_type_1:[nr of food types for food type 1]
(food_subtype_1 - [price]) (food_subtype_2 - [price]) etc.
food_type_2:[nr of food types for food type 2]
(food_subtype_1 - [price]) (food_subtype_2 - [price]) etc.
[nr of drinks]
(drink_1 - [price]) (drink_2 - [price]) etc.
```

So for example the input might be:

```C
2
Pizza:2
(Pizza Margherita - 23) (Pizza Con Pollo - 25)
Pasta:1
(Pasta Carbonara - 22)
3
(Coca Cola - 4) (Tea - 5) (Water - 2)
```

For this I am using some structures:

```C
typedef struct _food {
    char* name;
    int nrOfSubtypes;
    foodSubtype* subtypes;
} food;

typedef struct _foodSubtype {
    char* name;
    double price;
} foodSubtype;
```

For each type of structure I have functions that dynamically allocate the memory for the pointers:

```C
food createFood(int nrSubtypes) {
    food f;
    f.name = (char*) malloc(WORD_LENGTH* sizeof(char));
    f.nrOfSubtypes = nrSubtypes;
    f.subtypes = (foodSubtype*) malloc(f.nrOfSubtypes* sizeof(foodSubtype));
    for (int i = 0; i < f.nrOfSubtypes; ++i) {
        f.subtypes[i] = createSubtype();
    }
    return f;
}

foodSubtype createSubtype() {
    foodSubtype f;
    f.name = (char*) malloc(WORD_LENGTH* sizeof(char));
    f.price = 0;
    return f;
}
```

Now, in my reading function I take the input line by line and then parse it by separating it with `strtok`. One of the functions used is `parseFoodName`, which takes as parameters the line input that I just read and a pointer to a `food` variable:

```C
void parseFoodName(char *string, food *f) {
    char* name = (char*) malloc(WORD_LENGTH* sizeof(char));
    int nr;
    strcpy(name, strtok(string, ":"));
    string = strtok(NULL, "");
    nr = atoi(string);
    *f = createFood(nr);
    strcpy(f->name, name);
}
```

`parseFoodName` is called within `loadDataFromConsole` as follows:

```C
void loadDataFromConsole(int *nrOfFoodsAddr, food **foodsAddr) {
    printf("%s", INPUT_DATA_MSG);
    scanf("%d", nrOfFoodsAddr);
    getchar();
    *foodsAddr = (food*) malloc((*nrOfFoodsAddr+1)* sizeof(food));
    char *inputLine;
    inputLine = (char*) malloc(INPUT_LINE_LENGTH* sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < *nrOfFoodsAddr; ++i) {
        gets(inputLine);
        parseFoodName(inputLine, foodsAddr[i]);
        gets(inputLine);
        parseSubtypes(inputLine, foodsAddr[i]);
    }
    free(inputLine);
}
```

I have an array of `food` variables, so inside a `for` loop I call `parseFoodName` for each element of the array. The first time I call `parseFoodName`, everything works as expected, however the second time I get a segmentation fault at `*f = createFood(nr)`. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You haven’t included the calls to `parseFoodName`. (You did write `*f = parseFoodName(nr)`, but it wouldn’t look like that, since `parseFoodName` takes two parameters and doesn’t return anything.)

Comment: maybe you overflow the space you malloc'd

Comment: @Ry- I accidentally typed the wrong function. The segmentation fault is at `*f = createFood(nr)`. My bad. I corrected it.

Comment: Please still show how `parseFoodName` is called.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, code that includes `main` and all the exact function calls. Also, which exact line does it seg fault on - a debugger can tell you that.

Comment: @DianaVrabie A possible failure: `strcpy(name, strtok(string, ":"));` You never check how long input is. Would it work properly or not depends on WORD_LENGTH and input string.

Comment: Probably WORD_LENGTH is too small. Set the names to `NULL` initially and allocate the actual length plus 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line

```
*foodsAddr = (food*) malloc((*nrOfFoodsAddr+1)* sizeof(food));
```

you only set `foodsAddr[0]`.

You can fix this by adding this for loop right after the `malloc`.

```
for(int i = 1; i < *nrOfFoodsAddr; i++)
    foodsAddr[i] = foodsAddr[i - 1] + 1; // make foodsAddr[i] point to the next element after foodsAddr[i - 1]
```

or replace all `foodsAddr[i]` with `foodsAddr[0] + i`.

Comment: This fixed it! I'm new to pointers, could you please maybe explain what I was doing wrong and what your code does to make it work?

Comment: Basically your code allocated some bytes for `*nrOfFoodsAddr+1` food instances with `malloc`. `malloc` returns a pointer to the first byte. Casting it will give you `food*`. Since `*foodsAddr` = `*(foodsAddr+0)` = `foodsAddr[0]`, you only assigned a pointer to the first element, and the others are left untouched.
That's why your function only works for the first element.
My code iterates over the array of pointers and gives each element(pointer type) the address of the previous pointer + 1(foodsAddr[1] = foodsAddr[0]+1, foodsAddr[2] = foodsAddr[0]+2 and so on), so the addresses are all valid